# If the f-string like string formatting available in Julia?

Tags: python, string, formatting, julia

So I am new to Julia and learned various ways of string formatting. Mainly from websites similar to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatting-of-strings-in-julia/).

So I use f-strings a lot in Python, not a big fan of .format(). So I was wondering since someone created Formatting.jl Package to bring .format() like feature in Julia, is there any ongoing or useful package which does same for f-strings? Now I googled a bit about it too but didn't find anything.

What my main issue is that I want to replicate this behaviour:

```
a = 10
b = 20
print(f'The multiplication is = {a * b}')
```

In case anyone wondering what are f-strings, refer to [this](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with standard Julia strings:

```
x = "World!"
y = 42
greeting = "Hello $x, $(y^2) !" # gives "Hello World!, 1764 !"
```

See also here:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation

Edit:
The example in the comment above is

```
j = 10; b = 20
println("The numbers and their square are $j, $b and $(j^2), $(b^2)")
```

Comment: Well this isn't exactly what I was referring to.
So I was looking for this kind of functionality:

j = 10; b = 20
print(f'The numbers and their square are {j}, {b} and {j**2}, {b**2}')

I hope I am making sense here.

Does something like this exist in Julia?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the functionality above - see added example above.
It is just simpler than in Python ;-)

Comment: No, it's not doing the main thing I want it to do. Okay I think I didn't state it yet. So in Python's f-string, one can do, print(f'The multiply is {j * b}'). But this isn't something I am able to replicate in Julia. Now I hope I am a bit clear here.

Comment: print("The multiply is $(j * b)")

Comment: Okay, I understood what I was doing wrong and this is super silly and I can't believe I was making such a mistake. So I was trying to concat two strings using + sign inside the print this way and just now realized- in julia string concatination happens via *.

Well, sorry for pestering you so much. The day I learned in Julia that's how you concat strings, I knew one day this would cause some confusion.

Comment: No problem - the string concatination is Julia has a rather uncommon sign ;-)

Comment: I was wondering why they even decided to do that. Was there some mathematical reason behind it? Given how Julia is quite math friendly based language.

Comment: Yes, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#man-concatenation

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple packages, of which the least well known but my favourite is [PyFormattedStrings.jl](https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/PyFormattedStrings/T968L).

Compare:

| Package | Syntax |
| --- | --- |
| [PyFormattedStrings.jl](https://gitlab.com/aplavin/PyFormattedStrings.jl) | `f"Our yield is {harvest(crop):.3G} kg."` |
| [Fmt.jl](https://github.com/bicycle1885/Fmt.jl) | `f"Our yield is {$(harvest(crop)):.3G} kg."` |
| [Formatting.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl) | `fmt("Our yield is {:.3f} kg.", harvest(crop))` |

(Note that Formatting has no `g`/`G` support).

PyFormattedStrings.jl uses the [printf](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/) syntax, so eg aligning right is done with `{var:20g}`, and not `{var:>20g}` as in Python. Fmt.jl *does* use the Python syntax.
Neither package supports the `f"{4+4=}"` syntax of Python 3.8. (Though Julia has [@show](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@show)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want more control over numeric formatting than the default string interpolation, you can use the [Formatting.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl) in Julia, which provides Python f-string functionality.

Comment: As of 2023, do not use the Formatting.jl package. It has catastrophic correctness bugs and is unmaintained, see https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl/issues/108